# How to keep R studio from turning spaces into "." symbols. (Mac OS settings issue)

Tags: r, macos

In the most recent update to R Studio ( 2023.03.0+386 ) there has been an issue of turning 2 spaces into a period "."

For example if I were to type

```
x <- 1
```

everything is fine, however if I put two spaces in it adds the period.

```
x. <- 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution lies within my Mac OS and not R Studio. I found the solution [here](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/12/19/how-to-stop-your-mac-from-inserting-a-period-when-you-double-press-the-space-bar/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20don%27t%20want,ll%20be%20good%20to%20go.).

If you don’t want to insert a period when pressing the space bar twice, go to System Preferences > Keyboard, then select the Text tab. To the right of that window are several checkboxes for typing-related options. Simply uncheck the box labeled Add period with double-space, and you’ll be good to go.